# Applying a conditional replace function over every cell in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to subset a dataframe in R by checking if each value is present in a specific list and keeping it if it is. For instance in the following dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(A = sample(1:5, 5),
                B = sample(1:5, 5),
                C = sample(1:5, 5))
  A B C
1 2 2 1
2 3 3 3
3 1 4 4
4 4 5 2
5 5 1 5
```

How could I subset it to include only the values 1, 3 and 4, giving the following as a result:

```
  A B C
1 1
2 3 3 3
3 4 4
4 4 
5 1
```

It doesn't matter what happens to the missing values - they could be changed to NA if this is easier. From browsing similar questions it seems that lapply might do it, but as a novice I'm struggling to apply what I've seen to this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(47)
x <- data.frame(A = sample(1:5, 5),
                B = sample(1:5, 5),
                C = sample(1:5, 5))

# with lapply
keep_vals = c(1, 3, 4)
x[] = lapply(x, function(y) {
  y[! y %in% keep_vals] = NA
  return(y)
})

x
#    A  B  C
# 1  3  1  1
# 2  1 NA NA
# 3 NA NA  4
# 4  4  3 NA
# 5 NA  4  3
```

---

Or with a for loop:

```
set.seed(47)  # reset data
x <- data.frame(A = sample(1:5, 5),
                B = sample(1:5, 5),
                C = sample(1:5, 5))

keep_vals = c(1, 3, 4)
for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
  x[, i][!x[, i] %in% keep_vals] <- NA
}
x
#    A  B  C
# 1  3  1  1
# 2  1 NA NA
# 3 NA NA  4
# 4  4  3 NA
# 5 NA  4  3
```

---

With `dplyr`

```
x %>% mutate_all(
  ~replace(., !. %in% keep_vals, NA)
)
#    A  B  C
# 1  3  1  1
# 2  1 NA NA
# 3 NA NA  4
# 4  4  3 NA
# 5 NA  4  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Collapsing each row to the matching numbers, and adjusting each `length` to `ncol`. (Assuming you want to "left-align" your numbers, as shown in your expected output.)

```
d <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(apply(d, 1, function(x) {
  x <- x[x %in% c(1, 3, 4)]
  `length<-`(x, ncol(d))
}))), names(d))
d
#    A  B  C
# 1  1 NA NA
# 2  3  3  3
# 3  1  4  4
# 4  4 NA NA
# 5 NA NA NA
```

Since `apply` throws a matrix, we tell R that we want the `t`ranspose `as.data.frame` and `setNames` to restore those.

*Note,* that I changed line 5 of your example data so that it doesn't contain any of the matching numbers, so as not to make it too easy.

---

*Data*

```
d <- read.table(text="A B C
1 2 2 1
2 3 3 3
3 1 4 4
4 4 5 2
5 5 2 5", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `dplyr::bind_rows`

```
do.call(bind_rows,apply(x,1, function(a) a[a %in% c(1,3,4)]))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
      A     B     C
  <int> <int> <int>
1     4    NA    NA
2     1     1     1
3     3     3    NA
4    NA    NA     4
5    NA     4     3
```